# Find ratio of probabilities for a nuclear reaction to occur

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

I have the nuclear reaction $$D+D \to  {}^4\mathrm{He}(S) \to  {}^\rm 3He+n$$
($D$ is deuterium). Also the spin of $D$ is $s_1=s_2=1$.
I want to find the ratio $$\frac{\text{polarized }(P)}{\text{non-polarized }(N)}$$ for
$S=1$,
where $S$ is the spin of $^4\mathrm{He}(S)$, $P$ is the probability of the 
reaction to occur for $D$ nuclei being in state $\left|+1\right\rangle_z$ and $N$ is the 
probability of reaction to occur for $D$ nuclei non-polarized.

My attempt is to first find the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, I have $s_1=s_2=1$, $m_1=0$,$m_2=1$ (or $m_1=1$,$m_2=0$) $S=1$ and $M=1$,
so after 
some computations I find
$$|1,1 \rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |1,1;1,0 \rangle -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |1,1;0,1 \rangle$$
using the notation $|s_1,s_2;m_1,m_2 \rangle$
(since $M=+1$ then $m_1=0$, $m_2=1$ or $m_1=1$, $m_2=0$)
 so $$P=\langle 1,1;0,1|1,1 \rangle=\frac{1}{2}$$
Now I don't understand what it means for $D$ nuclei to be non-polarized, I think
it means that there is the same amount of $D$ in states $|+1{\rangle}_z$, $|0{\rangle}_z$
and $|-1{\rangle}_z$ but I don't know how to use this fact.
Can you help me procced from here?

Comment: Are you imagining few-MeV interactions, where you need to know details about the energy level structure of the $A=4$ system? Or are you imagining a sufficiently high energy where all of the spin and parity combinations in the system are equally available?